# phoenix app set timezone

Tags: timezone, phoenix-framework

on my server local time is:

```
Wed nov 16 23:34:01 +04 2016
```

Console my phoenix-applications:

```
#<DateTime(2016-11-16T19:34:01.751301Z Etc/UTC)>
```

I would like for my application the current time is equal to the system time. but I could not find how to configure it. Is there any way to set the time zone for the application?